# Combine Get-Item with Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell

I thought I was getting all the containers with 
`$containers = Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}`,
but it appears to return back just subdirectories of my `$Path`.  I really want `$containers` to contain `$Path` and its sub-directories.  I tried this:

```
$containers = Get-Item -path $Path | ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
$containers += Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
```

But it does not let me do this.  Am I using `Get-ChildItem` wrong, or how do I get $containers to include the `$Path` and its $subdirectories by combining a Get-Item and Get-ChildItem with -recurse?

Answer (score 5):

In your first call to get-item you are not storing the results in an array (because it's only 1 item). This means you can't append the array to it in your `get-childitem` line. Simply force your containers variable to be an array by wrapping the result in an `@()` like this:

```
$containers = @(Get-Item -path $Path | ? {$_.psIscontainer})
$containers += Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | ? {$_.psIscontainer}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-Item` to get the parent path and `Get-ChildItem` to get the parent childrens:

```
$parent = Get-Item -Path $Path
$child = Get-ChildItem -Path $parent -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
$parent,$child
```

Comment: I tried this with: $containters = $parent,$child, but what you get is $containers = {upgrade},{in,out}--in that, two arrays added to $containers.

Comment: Try: $containers = $child+$parent

Comment: @ShayLevy I don't think that will work since you are trying to add an array to a string. But this should:  $containers = @($child)+$parent

Comment: @zdan nor $child or $parent are strings, both contain DirectoryInfo objects. Do you get different results?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
$containers = Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | Where-object {$_.psIscontainer}
```

What I end up with is the `$path` and all sub-directories of `$path`.

In your example, you have `$.psIscontainer` but it should be `$_.psIscontainer`.  That might have also been the problem with your command.

Comment: I have $Path = \\share\place with two subdirectories called in and out for example.  When I run your suggestion I still get $containers = {in,out}, not {\\share\place,in,out}.  This is confusing.

Comment: If you want the full name then you need to select the full name: $containers = Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | Where-object {$_.psIscontainer} | Select-Object FullName

Comment: This does not seem to work; still get just subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) with a script block:

```
$containers = . {
    get-item $path | where-object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }
    get-childItem $path -recurse | where-object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }
}
```